# How to use a list of values as label in Python's Machine Learning

Tags: python, machine-learning, multilabel-classification

I'm stuck with a problem where I don't know how to use a list as labels in a ML model. Basically I have a Data Frame as follows:
[image: Data Frame]

My feature set is a list of numbers, and my label is also a list of numbers. How do I associate one with the other? I already worked with binary labels, but I can't manage-it with non-binary labels.

ps: I'm aware that my data lack of preprocessing, and I'm loading only a tiny piece of the whole for processing speed reasons

EDIT - Sorry for not being clear enough: Each number is a word. My featureset is a text, my label is a title. I'm trying to build a model that given a text, it generates a title, based on the trained model

Comment: Can you give an example of "associate one with the other"?

Comment: Each number is a word. My featureset is a text, my label is a title. I'm trying to build a model that given a text, it generates a title, based on the trained model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to try sklearn's `MultiLabelBinarizer()`. Take a look at [this post](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2018/05/07/multi-label-classification-with-keras/)

Comment: I already have  seen this method and doesn't fit in my problem. I don't have multiple labels, I have one label that can have multiple values i.e. not-binary. Thank's anyways ^^

Comment: Recently I had a similar project -> every label contains multiple values (and values of each label are not binary). And `MultiLabelBinarizer()` will convert those `non-binary` values of a label into `binary representation`. I suggest you to read the post eagerly :)

Comment: Don't hesitate to ask if you need any further help and please upvote the answer if it was helpful

Comment: interestingly my doubt was exactly at the most critical point of the algorithm, according to the article. Thanks man, really helped

Answer (score 0):

https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/multiclass.html#multilabel-classification-format You should use multilabel approaches to solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try the OneHotEncoding which is built-in in pandas "get_dummies".

As per my understanding your data looks like(giving example of 'y' here):

```
df
 
   a  b  y
0  1  2  1
1  4  5  2
2  7  1  3
3  4  7  1
4  6  0  3
5  7  9  2
6  8  1  1
```

where each number in y column represent each class.

so what you can do is:

`new_y = pd.get_dummies(df['y'], drop_first=True)`

`It would be very helpful if you post some sample data here and what exactly you are willing to achieve.`

PS : Apart from that you will have to use Categorical_CrossEntropy as loss calculation.